# How to implement 2 user account systems for the same website?

Tags: django, session, web, user-accounts

My website has an account system for site users. Now I need to implement another account system for affiliates.

I can add another user table for affiliates, and attach the 'loggedIn' status in session, but the 2 account shares the same session policy: if the session cookie expires for one account system, it also does for the other.

How I can implement the new account system that is not affected by the old one?

I am using Django by the way.

Comment: Are you sure the session expires for both the accounts if it does for one? Because I also have something similar in one of my projects and it works fine.

Comment: @weasel I used Django's built-in session framework.